# How to enable custom setting for emmet-vim in NeoVim using Vim Plug

Tags: vim, neovim, emmet

I'm using nvim and have loaded **mattn/emmet-vim** with **vim plug**. It works well with all files it's supposed to.

However, for Jekyll's liquid files I'd like to use the same setup as html.

For some reason, when the file is detected as "liquid" emmet simply does not work, no suggestions, keybindings dont suggest anything,

How can I get emmet to work with liquid files?

My .vimrc has the following (excepts):

```
  3 call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
  4 
  5   Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
  6   Plug 'junegunn/fzf', {'do': { ->fzf#install()}}
  7   Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
  8   Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
  9   Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
 10   Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
 11   Plug 'tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight'
 12   Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
 13   Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
 14   Plug 'preservim/nerdcommenter'
 15   Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
 16   Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
 17   Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
 18   Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
 19   Plug 'maxmellon/vim-jsx-pretty'
 20   Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
 21   Plug 'tpope/vim-liquid'
 22 
 23 call plug#end()
....
 49 " EMMET-VIM {{{
 50   let g:user_emmet_settings = { 
 51   \  'liquid' : { 
 52   \    'extends' : 'html', 
 53   \  }, 
 54   \} 
 55 "}}}
```

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.